# При использовании параметра выдается системная ошибка

Tags: параметры, bigquery, google-data-studio

Есть таблица в Bigquery с 80 тыс. строками.
Создал источник, в котором через SQL запрос обращаюсь к таблице.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `data.analytics`
WHERE
  `date` BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE)
  AND PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
  AND (Typeproduct is null or Typeproduct in unnest(@Typeproduct) )
;
```

Создал параметр Typeproduct тип текст с 2 параметрами для фильтрации в SQL запросе.

Если переключаю значения параметров по умолчанию в источнике, то все работает.
Во всех визуализациях стоит значение по умолчанию.
Если в отчете меняю фильтр(ниспадающий список) по этому параметру, то выдается ошибка.

> Системная ошибка В сервисе "Студия данных" произошла системная ошибка.
>
> Параметры отчета изменились, поэтому текущие значения больше
> недействительны. Чтобы исправить это, откройте панель "Ресурсы" и
> проверьте содержания раздела "Параметры" для диаграммы, группы,
> страницы или отчета.

Как и писал выше, все стоит по умолчанию. На небольших данных делал пример из 5 строчек. Все работает. Куда копать, что делать?

Comment: Я не понимаю зачем тут unnest? Аргументом unnest должен быть массив, а тут текст. Поскольку параметр в DataStudio типа Текст, то можно просто сравнить `Typeproduct = @Typeproduct` или если использовать unnest (менее эффективно) - `Typeproduct in unnest([@Typeproduct])`.
Я попробовал воспроизвести - получаю `Second argument of IN UNNEST must be an array but was STRING` при попытке создать источник данных с упрощенным подобным запросом.

Comment: @Michael  В Typeproduct можно выбрать сразу несколько значений. 
Если бы только один вариант, то я бы использовал `Typeproduct = @Typeproduct` 

По этому я взял пример из документации:
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10588439

Вот этот пример:

**Use a multi-select string parameter. Note the use of UNNEST to flatten the list of values:**

`SELECT * from user.users as user WHERE display_name in UNNEST(@name);`